# Where can I find huge linear system datasets?

Tags: dataset, linear-algebra

I have been searching the web, but I have not found huge linear systems datasets.

Do you know any web site where I can get one, let's say of size $100000 \times 100000$ or maybe a little bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the University of Florida Sparse Matrix Collection at http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/matrices/ has what you are looking for.

The other answers to the question ["Where can one obtain good data sets/test problems for testing algorithms/routines?"](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/46/where-can-one-obtain-good-data-sets-test-problems-for-testing-algorithms-routine) on the Computational Science SE may also be useful for you.